# Filter numpy array on multiple columns conditions

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array as below.

```
value array:
[[ 5 58  7 22  8 50]
[ 7 22  9 22 10 12]
[ 1 44  4 12  8 50]
[ 1  4  4  2  8  2]
[ 7 17  8 17 10  7]
[ 7 17  9 17 10  7]
[ 8 17  9 17 10  7]
[ 8  1  9  1 10  1]
[ 8  2  9  7 10 37]]
```

I use this code to get the even columns of values and group it, as this:

```
k=3
index_feature = list(range(0, 2 * k, 2))
group_feature = npi.group_by(value_array[:,index_feature]).split(value_array[:, index_feature])
```

group_feature:
 (array([[1, 4, 8]]), array([[5, 7, 8]]), array([[ 7,  8, 10]]), array([[ 7,  9, 10]]), array([[ 8,  9, 10]]))

And now i want to filter like this:
if column 0, 2, 4 equal 1, 4, 8 which [1, 4, 8] is a element in group_feature, and get results is:

```
[[4,2,2]]
```

Likely, if is array([[ 8,  9, 10]])) i will get:

```
[[17, 17, 7]
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 7, 37]]
```

How i can do it?

Comment: In your excitement you may have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: my question is how i get the result? My numpy array is very large.